# How to pass/inject more than one HttpClient parameter to a typed HttpClientClass?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I want to register a typed HttpClient as here [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests#implement-your-typed-client-classes-that-use-the-injected-and-configured-httpclient).
Basically, the approach should be

services.AddHttpClient();

normally the pattern of these classes receive only the HttpClient class as a parameter and you implement the logic to call the endpoint. In my case, I need to use 2 HttpClient inside my MyHttpClient, one that pings the endpoint and the other one that talks with an IdentityProvider to discover the refreshEndpoints to refresh my cookies.

```
public class MyHttpClient : IMyHttpClient
{
    public MyHttpClient (HttpClient httpClient, 
                         HttpClient refreshHttpClient)
    {
    }
}
```

If I am trying to resolve from a controller an IMyHttpClient, I get an error saying it can't resolve an HttpClient.

In the GitHub code on line 43 [AddHttpClient](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpClientFactory/blob/6fae77bfaa08e509ca34817d08d4f5e7d019e343/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/DependencyInjection/HttpClientFactoryServiceCollectionExtensions.cs) you can see that is calling 
DefaultTypedHttpClientFactory. 
If you go to the implementation of the [DefaultTypedHttpClientFactory implementation](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpClientFactory/blob/f30c84e8b69e9503cb0f471f51417ceee1ef4817/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/DefaultTypedHttpClientFactory.cs) you will notice that is a generic type. And when it calls CreateClient it only passes one parameter to the constructor on line 39.

The only workaround I am seeing here is to not create a typed client and register a normal class that receives an IHttpClientFactory and create and configure my clients on the fly, not as typed.
Any other idea?

Comment: why have 2? could you hide the one behind another typed client?

Comment: if I do that, then I need to create a regular class that receives both client implementations to orchestrate everything I need there. Something I would like to do it in one. In my scenario, I would like to make a call to an endpoint, but before doing that I would like to see if I need to refresh a token, which needs to be done by another http channel call

Comment: FWIW, this breaks SRP (single-responsibility principle). There's two different sets of logic here, which screams for two different classes. I'd actually even say *three* classes. One to work with your actual `HttpClient`, one to do the refresh stuff, and then a *third* to orchestrate the two. The third would be the one you'd actually inject in places like controllers.

Comment: How are `httpClient` and `refreshHttpClient` different, exactly? Not clear on why you need two. The `HttpClient` class is thread-safe so you ought to be able to use it both for the ping and for the discovery, unless there is some difference.

Comment: @JhonWu the discovery endpoint is different from the endpoint the HttpClient should do

Comment: @ChrisPratt basically is one to work with my HttpClient and the other one to do the refresh, but the implementation of the refresh sets configurations that the other one should see, like the name of the cookie, thats why I want to set the whole responsability to my class

Comment: More likely than not, the entire architecture is actually wrong here. Generally speaking, the API itself should negotiate with IdentityServer directly. It sounds like you're trying to have it disconnected from IdentityServer but still somehow authorize it using IdentityServer, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I agree with you that the API should negotiate with the identity provider, but sometimes, if the cookie expires you want to refresh with the endpoints manually, not letting the user to go through the whole process again letting the api as well to negotiate, you can step in the middle and refresh with the endpoints of the identity provider yourself

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The cookie is the individual user's authenticated state. If it expires, it should be required to re-authenticate. Otherwise, there's no point in having it expire at all, i.e. just make it far future expires and keep the user "logged in" indefinitely. Of course, there's security concerns that go with that.

Comment: Communication to the API via the web app is covered by client credentials and is independent of user auth, or even if there's an active user at all. The web app would authenticate with IdentityServer via client credentials and request the scope of the API, which then gives it access to utilize that API.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190648/discussion-between-zinov-and-chris-pratt).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't. You'll either need to inject another service layer or `IHttpClientFactory` directly

**Another service**

```
public class MyRefreshClient
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public MyRefreshClient(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    ...
}

public class MyHttpClient : IMyHttpClient
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    private readonly MyRefreshClient _refreshClient;

    public MyHttpClient(HttpClient httpClient, MyRefreshClient refreshClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
        _refreshClient = refreshClient;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
services.AddHttpClient<MyRefreshClient>(c => { ... });
services.AddHttpClient<MyHttpClient>(c => { ... });
```

**Inject `IHttpClientFactory` (and use named clients)**:

```
public class MyHttpClient : IMyHttpClient
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    private readonly HttpClient _refreshClient;

    public MyHttpClient(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("MyHttpClient");
        _refreshClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("MyRefreshClient");
    }
}
```

Then:

```
services.AddHttpClient("MyHttpClient", c => { ... });
services.AddHttpClient("MyRefreshClient", c=> { ... });
```

Comment: I wanted to pass username and password as parameters as `string` and I didn't know how to do it but your response suggested me that I can user `Options` object and inject it.